# Seeking for Android Java AES Encryption , NDK C/C++ Decryption and viceversa source code example

Tags: java, c++, c, android-ndk, openssl

I am looking for any Android java AES 256 or AES 512 crypto library which is compatible with NDK openSSL library in C/C++ source code example. I want to encrypt in Java and pass it to C and decrypt there and vice versa depending on our application scenario. Please help me out with any example . I tried myself with the following code in java and c .but it is not working .

my java side is :

```
  SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
  Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES")
  cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
```

On NDK side i am using

```
 EVP_BytesToKey(
     EVP_aes_256_cbc(),  
     EVP_sha1(),         // SHA1
     Salt,               // 0
     KeyData,
     KeyLength,
     Rounds,             // 0
     aes_key, aes_iv);   // return buffers
```

Appreciate any responses ....

Answer (score 0):

Bouncy castle is the option. Used it working fine.